# What does [2 whole steps down & b flat down] mean for the guitar?

Tags: guitar, tuning

I know two steps down is C tuning, but what does the "b flat down" mean?

Comment: Give us an example of where you've seen this.

Comment: Is this about [B flat tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E2%99%AD_tuning)?

Comment: To me, that sounds like "C Standard Drop Bb" or just "Drop Bb", but I've never seen or heard it expressed that way

Comment: I'd be interested what songs play with this tuning

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you found this, but it sounds like a very roundabout way of describing drop Bb tuning. C Standard is CFBbEbGc, whereas Drop Bb lowers the bottom C a whole step to yield BbFBbEbGc. That's the only real sensible way I could think to interpret "b flat down".